# Django POST request returns NONE

Tags: python, html, django, post

so ive been serching for a solution for about a week now I just need the data from a hidden label within a form witch should be no problem but instead of the data from the label i just get 'NONE'

Template (form):

```
{% for Gerecht in Gerechten %}
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
  </section>
  <section class="u-clearfix u-custom-color-2 u-valign-middle u-section-2" id="sec-a9e5">
    <div class="u-clearfix u-gutter-0 u-layout-wrap u-layout-wrap-1">
      <div class="u-layout" style="">
        <div class="u-layout-row" style="">
          <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-image u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-shading u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-image-1" src="" data-image-width="4880" data-image-height="3253" style="  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.25), rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), url('{% static '/img/{{ Gerecht.afbeelding }}' %}')">
            <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1" src=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-custom-color-1 u-layout-cell u-right-cell u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-layout-cell-2">
            <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-2">
              <h2 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-white u-text-1"> {{ Gerecht.naam }}</h2>
              <p class="u-text u-text-default u-text-white u-text-2">Duur: {{ Gerecht.duur }} u              </p>                 
               <input type="submit" value="ga naar gerecht" class="u-active-custom-color-3 u-align-left u-border-1 u-border-active-custom-color-3 u-border-hover-custom-color-3 u-border-white u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-hover-custom-color-3 u-none u-radius-12 u-text-active-white u-text-hover-white u-btn-2" name="btnZieRecept">
              <label name="id" style="display: none;" value="{{ Gerecht.id }}">{{ Gerecht.id }}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
    {% endfor %}
```

My views.py:

```
    if request.POST.get('btnZieRecept'):
        PK =  request.POST.get('id')
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.NOTSET)
        logging.debug(request.POST.get('id'))
        return redirect('GerechtPreview', PK=PK)
```

So here PK=None and i dont know why

```
 def GerechtPreview(request, PK):
    obj = Gerecht.objects.get(pk=PK)
    ingList=[]
    for f in obj.bijIngridiënten:
        ingList.append(f)
    for f in obj.Hoofdingridiënten:
        ingList.append(f)
    return render(request, 'GerechtPreview.html', {"obj":obj, "ingList":ingList})
```

My urls.py:

```
  path('Gerechten.html', views.Gerechten, name="Gerechten.html")
  re_path(r'^GerechtPreview.html/(?P<PK>\w+)/$', views.GerechtPreview, name="GerechtPreview"),
```

Annyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't look like you are using any Django forms in your template. If your form is based on a model, I'd pass the "ModelForm" into your context via the view.
2. A hidden field in a form looks like this usually:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="HVjtndYO...1DIkUex7">
```

You should be able to see an example of this on your current form if you inspect the HTML (because of `{% csrf_token %}`)

I'm no HTML expert by any means; I've never seen it done through a `<label>` tag but maybe you can. I would just recommend trying it with an `<input type="hidden"` and give it a name and a value, and see if that comes through in the `POST` request.